# GREP - How to find people who won more than 50 races

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to GREP drivers who won more than 50 races using Ubuntu.

This is the command that I am using:

```
cat f1.txt | grep -E " ([5-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])*" | sort -n -k5 | uniq -c | tail -n 5
```

```
Rank Country         Driver                      Races Wins
1   [United_Kingdom] Lewis_Hamilton                264 94
2   [Germany] Sebastian_Vettel                     254 53
3   [Spain] Fernando_Alonso                        311 32
4   [Finland] Kimi_Raikkonen                       326 21
5   [Germany] Nico_Rosberg                         206 23
6   [Germany] Michael_Schumacher                   307 91
7   [Finland] Valtteri_Bottas                      153 9
8   [United_Kingdom] Jenson_Button                 306 15
9   [Brazil] Felipe_Massa                          269 11
10  [Australia] Daniel_Ricciardo                   185 7
11  [Netherlands] Max_Verstappen                   116 9
12  [Australia] Mark_Webber                        215 9
13  [France] Alain_Prost                           199 51
14  [Mexico] Sergio_Perez                          188 0
15  [Brazil] Rubens_Barrichello                    322 11
16  [Brazil] Ayrton_Senna                          161 41
17  [United_Kingdom] David_Coulthard               246 13
18  [Germany] Nico_Hulkenberg                      180 0
19  [Brazil] Nelson_Piquet                         204 23
20  [United_Kingdom] Nigel_Mansell                 188 31
21  [Austria] Niki_Lauda                           173 25
22  [Finland] Mika_Hakkinen                        161 20
23  [Monaco] Charles_Leclerc                       56  2
24  [France] Romain_Grosjean                       178 0
25  [Austria] Gerhard_Berger                       210 10
26  [United_Kingdom] Jackie_Stewart                100 27
27  [United_Kingdom] Damon_Hill                    115 22
28  [Spain] Carlos_Sainz_Jr.                       115 0
29  [Germany] Ralf_Schumacher                      180 6
30  [Argentina] Carlos_Reutemann                   146 12
31  [Colombia] Juan_Pablo_Montoya                  94  7
32  [United_Kingdom] Graham_Hill                   177 14
33  [Brazil] Emerson_Fittipaldi                    145 14
34  [Italy] Riccardo_Patrese                       256 6
35  [Argentina] Juan_Manuel_Fangio                 58  24
36  [Italy] Giancarlo_Fisichella                   230 3
37  [United_Kingdom] Jim_Clark                     72  25
38  [Poland] Robert_Kubica                         97  1
39  [Australia] Jack_Brabham                       127 14
40  [Germany] Nick_Heidfeld                        183 0
41  [South_Africa] Jody_Scheckter                  112 10
42  [New_Zealand] Denny_Hulme                      112 8
43  [Italy] Jarno_Trulli                           252 1
44  [France] Jean_Alesi                            201 1
45  [Canada] Jacques_Villeneuve                    164 11
46  [France] Jacques_Laffite                       176 6
47  [Switzerland] Clay_Regazzoni                   131 5
48  [Australia] Alan_Jones                         116 12
49  [Sweden] Ronnie_Peterson                       123 10
50  [New_Zealand] Bruce_McLaren                    102 4
51  [Russian_Federation] Daniil_Kvyat              107 0
52  [United_Kingdom] Eddie_Irvine                  147 4
53  [France] Pierre_Gasly                          61  1
54  [United_Kingdom] Stirling_Moss                 72  16
55  [Italy] Michele_Alboreto                       194 5
56  [Belgium] Jacky_Ickx                           115 8
57  [France] Rene_Arnoux                           149 7
58  [United_Kingdom] John_Surtees                  111 6
59  [United_States] Mario_Andretti                 128 12
60  [United_Kingdom] James_Hunt                    92  10
61  [France] Esteban_Ocon                          64  0
62  [Germany] Heinz-Harald_Frentzen                157 3
63  [United_Kingdom] John_Watson                   152 5
64  [Thailand] Alexander_Albon                     35  0
65  [Finland] Keke_Rosberg                         114 5
66  [Denmark] Kevin_Magnussen                      116 0
67  [France] Patrick_Depailler                     95  2
68  [Italy] Alberto_Ascari                         36  132
69  [United_States] Dan_Gurney                     86  4
70  [Belgium] Thierry_Boutsen                      163 3
71  [United_Kingdom] Mike_Hawthorn                 48  3
72  [Italy] Nino_Farina                            36  5
73  [Canada] Lance_Stroll                          75  0
74  [Japan] Kamui_Kobayashi                        75  0
75  [Germany] Adrian_Sutil                         128 0
76  [United_Kingdom] Lando_Norris                  35  0
77  [Italy] Elio_de_Angelis                        109 2
78  [United_Kingdom] Paul_di_Resta                 59  0
79  [Austria] Jochen_Rindt                         60  6
80  [United_States] Richie_Ginther                 52  1
81  [Canada] Gilles_Villeneuve                     67  6
82  [Finland] Heikki_Kovalainen                    111 1
83  [France] Patrick_Tambay                        116 2
84  [France] Didier_Pironi                         70  3
85  [United_States] Phil_Hill                      51  3
86  [United_Kingdom] Martin_Brundle                158 0
87  [United_Kingdom] Johnny_Herbert                161 3
88  [France] Francois_Cevert                       47  1
89  [Sweden] Stefan_Johansson                      79  0
90  [New_Zealand] Chris_Amon                       97  0
91  [Argentina] Jose_Froilan_Gonzalez              29  2
92  [France] Jean-Pierre_Beltoise                  85  1
93  [France] Olivier_Panis                         157 1
94  [United_Kingdom] Tony_Brooks                   41  6
95  [Venezuela] Pastor_Maldonado                   95  1
96  [France] Maurice_Trintignant                   86  2
97  [Mexico] Pedro_Rodriguez                       53  2
98  [Germany] Jochen_Mass                          105 1
99  [United_Kingdom] Derek_Warwick                 147 0
100 [United_States] Eddie_Cheever                  132 0
101 [Switzerland] Jo_Siffert                       97  2
102 [Italy] Alessandro_Nannini                     77  1
103 [Russian_Federation] Vitaly_Petrov             57  0
104 [United_Kingdom] Peter_Revson                  30  2
105 [Italy] Andrea_de_Cesaris                      208 0
106 [Italy] Lorenzo_Bandini                        44  1
107 [Brazil] Carlos_Pace                           72  1
108 [Germany] Wolfgang_von_Trips                   27  2
109 [France] Jean-Eric_Vergne                      58  0
110 [France] Jean_Behra                            57  0
111 [Germany] Timo_Glock                           91  0
112 [Italy] Luigi_Villoresi                        33  0
113 [United_Kingdom] Peter_Collins                 36  3
114 [United_Kingdom] Innes_Ireland                 52  1
115 [Austria] Alexander_Wurz                       69  0
116 [Italy] Luigi_Musso                            25  1
117 [Japan] Takuma_Sato                            90  0
118 [Italy] Piero_Taruffi                          18  1
119 [Sweden] Jo_Bonnier                            106 1
120 [Spain] Pedro_de_la_Rosa                       105 0
121 [Brazil] Bruno_Senna                           46  0
122 [Finland] Mika_Salo                            110 0
123 [Italy] Luigi_Fagioli                          8   1
124 [United_Kingdom] Mark_Blundell                 61  0
125 [United_States] Harry_Schell                   63  0
126 [France] Jean-Pierre_Jarier                    135 0
127 [Sweden] Gunnar_Nilsson                        31  1
128 [Spain] Jaime_Alguersuari                      46  0
129 [Italy] Ivan_Capelli                           93  0
130 [United_States] Jim_Rathmann                   12  1
131 [Brazil] Felipe_Nasr                           39  0
132 [United_Kingdom] Mike_Hailwood                 51  0
133 [Switzerland] Sebastien_Buemi                  55  0
134 [Germany] Hans_Joachim_Stuck                   74  0
135 [United_Kingdom] Mike_Spence                   36  0
136 [South_Africa] Tony_Maggs                      26  0
137 [Belgium] Stoffel_Vandoorne                    41  0
138 [Italy] Vitantonio_Liuzzi                      80  0
139 [Italy] Teo_Fabi                               63  0
140 [United_States] Masten_Gregory                 40  0
141 [France] Jean-Pierre_Jabouille                 49  2
142 [United_States] Sam_Hanks                      9   1
143 [United_Kingdom] Piers_Courage                 27  0
144 [Italy] Eugenio_Castellotti                    18  0
145 [United_States] Bill_Vukovich                  5   2
146 [Brazil] Nelson_Piquet_Jr.                     28  0
147 [United_Kingdom] Tom_Pryce                     42  0
148 [United_Kingdom] Roy_Salvadori                 48  0
149 [United_States] Jimmy_Bryan                    9   1
150 [Belgium] Olivier_Gendebien                    16  0
151 [Italy] Antonio_Giovinazzi                     37  0
152 [France] Louis_Rosier                          39  0
153 [Sweden] Marcus_Ericsson                       97  0
154 [Italy] Pierluigi_Martini                      119 0
155 [Italy] Felice_Bonetto                         16  0
156 [Italy] Ludovico_Scarfiotti                    11  1
157 [Germany] Karl_Kling                           12  0
158 [Italy] Stefano_Modena                         73  0
159 [Switzerland] Marc_Surer                       82  0
160 [Netherlands] Jos_Verstappen                   106 0
161 [United_Kingdom] Stuart_Lewis-Evans            14  0
162 [France] Robert_Manzon                         28  0
163 [Japan] Satoru_Nakajima                        74  0
164 [Italy] Vittorio_Brambilla                     74  1
165 [Brazil] Roberto_Moreno                        43  0
166 [Ireland] Derek_Daly                           49  0
167 [United_Kingdom] Mike_Parkes                   6   0
168 [United_States] Rodger_Ward                    12  1
169 [Italy] Giancarlo_Baghetti                     26  1
170 [Austria] Karl_Wendlinger                      41  0
171 [Austria] Christian_Klien                      49  0
172 [Germany] Rolf_Stommelen                       55  0
173 [Italy] Bruno_Giacomelli                       69  0
174 [United_Kingdom] Jonathan_Palmer               84  0
175 [Argentina] Roberto_Mieres                     17  0
176 [Sweden] Reine_Wisell                          23  0
177 [Brazil] Cristiano_da_Matta                    28  0
178 [Mexico] Hector_Rebaque                        41  0
179 [United_Kingdom] Jackie_Oliver                 50  0
180 [United_States] Johnnie_Parsons                10  1
181 [United_Kingdom] Peter_Arundell                13  0
182 [Brazil] Christian_Fittipaldi                  40  0
183 [France] Henri_Pescarolo                       57  0
184 [Belgium] Paul_Frere                           11  0
185 [United_States] Tony_Bettenhausen              13  0
186 [United_Kingdom] Cliff_Allison                 16  0
187 [United_Kingdom] Richard_Attwood               17  0
188 [United_Kingdom] Peter_Gethin                  30  1
189 [France] Philippe_Streiff                      54  0
190 [Italy] Arturo_Merzario                        57  0
191 [Switzerland] Rudi_Fischer                     7   0
192 [United_States] Johnny_Thomson                 9   0
193 [Germany] Hans_Herrmann                        18  0
194 [New_Zealand] Howden_Ganley                    36  0
195 [France] Eric_Bernard                          45  0
196 [Finland] Jyrki_Jarvilehto                     62  0
197 [Brazil] Mauricio_Gugelmin                     74  0
198 [Brazil] Pedro_Diniz                           99  0
199 [United_States] Troy_Ruttman                   8   1
200 [United_States] Lee_Wallard                    2   1
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: That guy at rank 68 is special. He won 132 out of 36 races.

Comment: Interestingly the guy at 68, has 13 wins and 2 championships, so maybe 132 wins is some bad joining of different data, also he drove 33 races, but died at 36, so maybe the number of races, 36 in this post, is also some bad data extraction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alberto_Ascari

Comment: This is a sample data form to practice my abilitiies using grep. The data may not reflect the reality.

Comment: @The_Liner Well then, the most important lesson you can learn from this is that you should not force a specific tool on a problem.  This is not a pattern matching problem, so `grep` should not be the tool go for first.

Comment: I agree with you, but this is a task that I have to figure it out myself, if I'm required to used grep, that means it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use awk, this will return all entries where the 5th field, which is wins, is larger than 50, or is not a number.

```
awk '$5 > 50' f1.txt
```

You get this

```
Rank Country         Driver                      Races Wins
1   [United_Kingdom] Lewis_Hamilton                264 94
2   [Germany] Sebastian_Vettel                     254 53
6   [Germany] Michael_Schumacher                   307 91
13  [France] Alain_Prost                           199 51
68  [Italy] Alberto_Ascari                         36  132
```

Since in this case this is the last field in line you can also use

```
awk '$NF > 50' f1.txt
```

---

If you really want to use grep you can use something like this, from the answer made by Greg Fenton, but you need to change `-E` to `-P` to use Perl regex, add `\b` to indicate that the digit is following a word boundary, so no digits or letter right before it, and change the first `\d` in three digit part to `[1-9]`, to not have three digit numbers with leading 0

```
grep -P '\b([5-9][1-9]|60|[1-9]\d\d)$' f1.txt
```

This is taking that there are only two or three digit wins.

**\b** means word boundary, it means there should be no digits or letters before the first digit
**()** means after word boundary you need to have what is defined inside the brackets.
**[5-9][1-9]** means there should be two digits, where first digit is 5-9 and other is 1-9, which means it will catch numbers 51-99 with exclusion of 60.
**|** means or operator and since 60 is excluded in previous regex `[5-9][1-9]` we say or 60.
**|[1-9]\d\d** means or three digits where first digit is 1-9 followed by any two digits, `[1-9]\d\d` could have also been `[1-9][0-9][0-9`]
**$** means the end of line, after the last digit there should be end of line, this is so you don't catch numbers that are not in the last field, that are not followed by end of line.

So basically grep says look for word boundary, followed by two or three digit number larger than 50, followed by end of line.

---

This part `[5-9][1-9]|60` finds two digit numbers 51-99 and this part `[1-9]\d\d` finds three digits numbers where first digit is 1-9, if you want to use more then three digits the add another or operation with `|` like

```
grep -P '\b([5-9][1-9]|60|[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d\d\d)$' f1.txt
```

The above would be for four digits.

If you would want to use any number of digits then use something like this

```
grep -P '\b([5-9][1-9]|60|[1-9]\d\d)\d*$' f1.txt
```

If for some reason Perl regex doesn't work in your grep you can try extended regex

```
grep -E '\b([5-9][1-9]|60|[1-9][0-9][0-9])[0-9]*$' f1.txt
```

Comment: I tried on Linux Terminal but it does not show anything, am I doing something wrong? p.s. the awk command works perfectly though.

Comment: what is your grep version, grep -V, make sure you are using grep -P not grep -E, if you use -E then you can't use \d you have to use [0-9] in place of it

Comment: grep (GNU grep) 3.4

Comment: that's the same version as mine, are you using -P, seems to me like you are not using -P option, if you don't say to use Perl regex to grep it doesn't work

Comment: I copied and pasted, the awk command works, the grep command works but it does not show anything.

Comment: try the -E version, I edited my answer, also try typing it out, maybe some copy paste issue

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn not work. When I remove the round brackets, it works but it does not include 132 value, I just need to include this value to conclude this task.

Comment: If you remove round brackets that will also include numbers in other fields like Races and Rank. Edit your question and add exactly what command are you running and what is the output of the command, and what is the exact input

Comment: I came out with this command: `cat f1.txt | grep -E " ([5-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])*" | sort -n -k5 | uniq -c | tail -n 5`

Comment: what is uniq -c suppose to do, every line is only once so why count them, also if you don't have \b before digits you will also catch stuff like 099 or a99, characters before digits, and if you don't have $ or \b at the end after digits you will catch stuff like 99b, characters after digits. You also don't need cat you can grep directly on the file

Comment: Good question that's what I wonder why, if I keep $, it won't show me anything, I have to remove it in order to make it work. I just removed the "uniq -c". The "\b is not neccessary as it only catches numbers anyway.

Comment: If you don't put $ you catch numbers that are not on the end of the line, so you get numbers in races and rank field larger then 50, I am not sure what you have in f1.txt on your end, you have something after the win numbers in those lines then, if it doesn't catch anything

Comment: The full data form is attached in the question, that's what I am working on. If you find any better solution using only "grep -E", please let me know, for now I keep this command as long as it works fine. Thanks for your time man!

Answer (score 0):

for `grep` (if you really need it over `awk`) that is:

```
grep -E '[[:blank:]]0*(5[1-9]|[6-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])[0-9]*$' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to the need to use `grep`, how about:

```
grep -E '([5-9]\d|\d\d\d)$' f1.txt
```

that yields:

```
$ grep -E '([5-9]\d|\d\d\d)$' f1.txt
1   [United_Kingdom] Lewis_Hamilton                264 94
2   [Germany] Sebastian_Vettel                     254 53
6   [Germany] Michael_Schumacher                   307 91
13  [France] Alain_Prost                           199 51
68  [Italy] Alberto_Ascari                         36  132
```

Comment: you need `-P` instead of `-E` for `\d`, also this `[5-9]\d` will match `50` too and `\d\d\d` will match `000` or `0001` or similar; or this will match on `abc123` etc

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it does not output anything?

Comment: The command I have above works just fine.  I am running on a MacBook Pro  v10.15.7 that has `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`.  As per the GREP man page, `-E` is exactly what I want to use (extended regular expressions).  `-P` (perl regexp) should work fine as well: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html

@αғsнιη - ah yes, nice catch on the "> 50".  My solution is ">= 50".  Bad on me.

Comment: Which OS are you running on?  Which version of grep are you using?